# Clear text on entry of telerik radsearchbox

Tags: asp.net, navigation, telerik

I need to clear the text of a telerik RadSearchBox when a user clicks on it.  How would I do that?
(If you can tell me how to do it on **any** entry to the RadSearchBox, including tabbing to it, that would be even more useful.)

Comment: Only via jQuery, as i understand from docs and telerik's forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
        var input = $find("<%=RadSearchBox1.ClientID%>").get_inputElement();
        jQuery(input).focus(function () {
            this.value = '';
        });
    });
```

There is no built-in method in the telerik control for this, but there are built-in javascript functions to get reference to the telerik control's html component parts.  The above code just uses jQuery to do what you want to accomplish (obviously replace "RadSearchBox1" with the server-side ID of your control.